# Express middleware not executing in correct order

Tags: node.js, express

I have put 2 middlewares one after the other, however the 2nd one always console.logs before the first one.

I tried async/await and .then and neither have worked for me. I think it has something to do with the API call in my first middleware.

```
app.use('/studies', function (req, res, next) {
    new Airtable({ apiKey: process.env.API_KEY }).base(process.env.BASE)('study').select({
        fields: ['title', 'image', 'keywords', 'affiliation'],
        view: 'default',
    }).firstPage((err, records) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err); return
        }

        console.log('first log');
        res.locals.studyObject = records;
    });
    next();
}) 

app.use('/studies', function (req, res) {  
    console.log('second log');          
    res.json(res.locals.studyObject);
})
```

My console.log looks like this:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
listening on port 5000
second log
first log
```

Comment: But your log in 1st mdw is inside an async callback, that's why

Comment: You want to force the call order then just call `next()` inside that callback too, athough this will block. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I edited my code to include what I want to do. I need to call res.locals.studyObject = records directly after the first console.log. Then I want to pass the res.locals.studyObject to my 2nd middleware to transform it further with another API call

Comment: @wei as first one is asynchronous, it is printed after getting a response from api

Comment: I suspected something like that. I tried making the first middleware an async function, with an await right before the new Airtable. But I still get the second log first. Is there something fundamentally wrong I am doing with the async await?

Comment: .then is also giving me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in the first middle you are calling asynchronous function and you are logging in the callback function. If you want to pass the handler to the next middleware after callback executed move `next()` inside the callback.

Try this,

```
app.use('/studies', function (req, res, next) {
    new Airtable({ apiKey: process.env.API_KEY }).base(process.env.BASE)('study').select({
        fields: ['title', 'image', 'keywords', 'affiliation'],
        view: 'default',
    }).firstPage((err, records) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err); return
        }

        console.log('first log');
        res.locals.studyObject = records;
        next();
    });
})
```

Comment: wow. that worked like a charm, I goofed hard. thank you very much

Comment: I also suggest you to learn about `event loop` if possible :) so you will understand the whole picture, [Here is a good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: wow, this was a very clear and informative video. I didn't realize stacks and tasks communicated in this manner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/studies', (req, res, next) => {
  new Airtable({apiKey: process.env.API_KEY}).base(process.env.BASE)('study').select({          
        fields: ['title', 'image', 'keywords', 'affiliation'], 
        view: 'default', 
        }).firstPage(function (err, records) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);
            return res.json(res.locals.studyObject);
        }
});
```